# Can Microchip TCP/IP stack implements two or more clients sockets at the same time?

Tags: embedded, tcp, microcontroller, microchip

I need to make one device communicate with 2 servers. Is it possible with Microchip TCP/IP stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could (and should) read the documentation, or ask Microchip support.

The [Microchip App. Note AN833](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00833c.pdf) describes the stack, and shows that it has configuration macros MAX_SOCKETS (value 1 to 253) and MAX_UDP_SOCKETS (1-254), both limited by available RAM, so I would say by implication; *yes*, if you have sufficient available RAM.

You should read this AN in its entirety to be sure that the stack will meet your requirements before commencing.  Asking on StackOverflow is no substitute for RTFM.